# Filling a fillable pdf with data from Excel

Tags: python, excel, pdf, pdftk

I am trying to fill out a fillable PDF with data that I have from Excel files. By doing some research online, I found that some people were suggesting of reading each row of the Excel file and to create a FDF from that. Then, using the FDF file, I can merge the FDF file with the original unfilled PDF file together using PDFTK, generating a finished PDF file. I feel like I understand the general concept, but I have no idea how to really do it.

I'm trying to write the code in Python, but I am still a beginner at it. I'm not even sure if I am supposed to import the PDFTK tool to Python as like an external resource.

Also, if there is a simpler or better way to do this, please suggest it to me.

Comment: Importing a tool would be the only way to be able to use it from Python which has no native support for PDF or FDF files.

Comment: As FDF is a text file, you can assemble it within Excel. It is also possible to join individual FDFs into one single file, which you then can run in Acrobat (if it works in pdftk, I don't know, however.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. I have two questions, first I don't know how to import a tool into Python. I installed pypdftk and imported it, but it tells me "WARNING:root:pdftk test call failed (PDFTK_PATH='pdftk')". I'm really not sure what that means.

And second, even if I'm able to build FDF files from excel, is there a way I can do it from Python when given the excel file?